# What is the correct way to select an <option> using Selenium's Python WebDriver

Tags: selenium, python, webdriver

I would like to select an `<option>` child of a `<select>` using the Python WebDriver.

I have a reference to the option `WebElement` I wish to select and have tried `select()` and `click()` methods but neither works.

What is the correct way to select an `<option>`?

Comment: Oh dearie me, **of course it works**. It was my fault for calling `click()` on the default `<option>`, which made it look like nothing had changed.

Comment: My test doesn’t work with `option.click()`, but it does work with `option.select()`. In the latest [webelement.py](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/detail?r=12729&path=/trunk/py/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py) source, `select` has been removed, and `click` must be used in it’s place. It will be interesting to see if my test works with the latest release.

Comment: Accepted solution is VERY SLOW. I recommend @Daniel Abel solution. It would be nice if OP accepted it, it keeps gaining upvotes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I work with dropdowns in Selenium Webdriver?](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12029/how-do-i-work-with-dropdowns-in-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The easiest way that I have found was to do something along the lines of:

```
el = driver.find_element_by_id('id_of_select')
for option in el.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
    if option.text == 'The Options I Am Looking For':
        option.click() # select() in earlier versions of webdriver
        break
```

This may have some runtime issues if there are a large number of options, but for us it suffices.

Also this code will work with multi-select

```
def multiselect_set_selections(driver, element_id, labels):
    el = driver.find_element_by_id(element_id)
    for option in el.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
        if option.text in labels:
            option.click()
```

Then you can transform the following field

```
# ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [addSelection | id=deformField7 | label=ALL]]
```

Into this call

```
multiselect_set_selections(driver, 'deformField7', ['ALL'])
```

Multiple selection errors like the following:

```
 # ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [addSelection | id=deformField5 | label=Apr]]
 # ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [addSelection | id=deformField5 | label=Jun]]
```

Will be fixed with a single call:

```
multiselect_set_selections(driver, 'deformField5', ['Apr', 'Jun'])
```

Comment: @JasonWard How are you iterating over the Web Element object in for loop. I tried the same and got a exception that the object is not iterable. Any suggestion. Thanks

Comment: @abhi Make sure you are using `find_elements_by_tag_name` and not `find_element_by_tag_name` (The `s` in `elements` matters).

Comment: Good solution, but not as good as Daniel Abel's proposed solution. Better off using the built in `Select` function

Comment: @ChrisB you are correct that his solution is better, however I am fairly certain that when this was response was written the `Select` function did not exist :)

Comment: Why did you edit my answer instead of adding your own?

Comment: Complain if I try to get the option tag value `55` or visibletext in `ID` `location ` at [this URL](https://www.wellsfargo.com/international-remittances/cost-estimator/)?. The weird things are `select.options` returns only `Select One` options when you loop through options, instead of return 3 options. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 78):

I think using [`selenium.webdriver.support.ui.Select`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.select.html) is the cleanest way:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

b = webdriver.Firefox()

# navigate to the page
select = Select(b.find_element_by_id(....))
print select.options
print [o.text for o in select.options] # these are string-s
select.select_by_visible_text(....)
```

Using this approach is also the fastest way. I wrote `fast_multiselect` as analogous function to `multiselect_set_selections`. On a test with 4 calls to `multiselect_set_selections` on lists of about 20 items each, the average running time is 16.992 seconds, where `fast_multiselect` is only 10.441 seconds. Also the latter is much less complicated.

```
 from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

 def fast_multiselect(driver, element_id, labels):
     select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id(element_id))
     for label in labels:
         select.select_by_visible_text(label)
```

Comment: Nice. Selenium auto-generated documentation just sucks.

Comment: This is the idiomatic approach. Too bad it isn't the accepted answer.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: My big question is **How is it so slow?** Why?  I don't understand... 10 seconds is way too long.

Answer (score 9):

Similar to Will's answer, but finds the `<select>` by its element name, and clicks based on the `<option>` text.

```
from selenium import webdriver
b = webdriver.Firefox()
b.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='element_name']/option[text()='option_text']").click()
```

Comment: This worked for me using `"//select[@name='element_name']/option[@value='2']"` to select an option by it's value (in case you are concerned about option text changing). It's well worth learning about xpath, IMO.  http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/locating-elements.html#locating-by-xpath

Comment: Yes, as @AdamStarrh, this only worked with `@value`

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem and was able to resolve it by finding the elements by xpath:

```
from selenium import webdriver
b = webdriver.Firefox()
#...some commands here
b.find_element_by_xpath("//select/option[@value='The Options I am Looking for']").click()
```

Answer (score 1):

easier way to manipulate the dropdowns

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver.get("link")
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('<given id name>'))
select.select_by_index(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the latest rewritten version (1.0.1) of facebook/php-webdriver:

```
$optionCssSelector = WebDriverBy::cssSelector("#order_images_row_wrapper .order-wrapper .merge-image-select option[value='2']");
$this->driver->findElements($optionCssSelector)[0]->click();
```

Comment: That's some mighty strange looking Python you've got there.