# Can't get Selenium to select option

Tags: selenium, python

I have been trying for a long time to get Selenium to select an option from a drop down select field. It appears not to be selecting the element whatsoever. Could the fact that it requires a reload link be causing issues?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import requests
import re

driver2 = webdriver.Chrome()
driver2.get("http://www.squawka.com/match-results")

el = driver2.find_element_by_id('league-filter-list')
for option in el.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
    if option.text == 'Football League Championship':
        option.click()
        break

driver2.quit()
```

Comment: Can you post the Source for the dropdown element itself? It'll help a lot of finding some other alternatives to select the dropdown.

Comment: paste your HTML code  here so that we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to click an invisible element, which won't work.

It's easiest to use the [select](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.select) class.

For an example, see Daniel Abel's answer in this thread: [What is the correct way to select an <option> using Selenium's Python WebDriver](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1355/what-is-the-correct-way-to-select-an-option-using-seleniums-python-webdriver)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
el = driver2.find_element_by_id('league-filter-list')
el.select_by_visible_text('Football League Championship')
```

Comment: We prefer answers to have context and not be simply code without explanation.

Comment: Jose could you elaborate on the difference between this answer and the OP? I think you're correct, but it's taking some heat for being code-only. It's one of those "give a fish, teach to fish" kind of things.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround for dropdown menus that dont have data before interaction you could simply click text after clicking on element.

```
findYourDropdown.Click
findSomeText.Click
```