# How to handle the exact position of runtime creating webelement in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium3

I've been writing a couple of tests using selenium for my website. However, I've not found a way to test multiselect dropdown with checkboxes that is filled by V-autocomplete(vuetifyjs) component . As an example, I want to select one of the locations that is displayed in an V-auto-complete list dropdown.

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath(//*[contains(@class, 'v-autocomplete')])
```

[image]

Comment: `driver.find_elements_by_xpath(//*[contains(@class, 'v-autocomplete')])` will return a list of elements, not a single entry. What is the output of your script?

Comment: Check out [What is the correct way to select an <option> using Selenium's Python WebDriver](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1355/what-is-the-correct-way-to-select-an-option-using-seleniums-python-webdriver)

Answer (score 0):

According to [software testing solutions](https://www.qasource.com/software-testing-company), you need to perform the following steps:-

1. Navigate to the desired dropdown and click on the same.

   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//desired xpath")
2. Get all the checkboxes in a webelement on the basis of a common property.

   checkBoxes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("type='checkbox'")
3. Run a loop on "checkBoxes" and use the get method to fetch the name/id of each and every checkbox.

   for c in checkBoxes:

   if(c.text() == desired_checkbox):

   c.click()